# How to create standard Report with record data as column labels?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I was asked to create a standard report to show data from master-detail object structure.

Sample Data looks like this:

[image]

and I am looking to create report as below:

[image]

I have tried Matrix report and other options but couldn't get it working.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the Name field contains only those three types of record then easiest way to accomplish as follows:

> Create formula fields

`Number of Bedrooms` which is type of Number and return the value from `Value` field.

`Number of Bathrooms` which is type of Number and return the value from `Value` field

`Floor Type` which is type of Text and return the value from `Value`

Expose those formula fields in the report and then create a simple tabular report the way you have shown in the picture.

Comment: We have around 10-15 different types. Also, even if I create formula field for each of those, this is how it is showing : https://imgur.com/a/TWYFMA1 I need only one row in the report. If there is a way to achieve this report without creating formula fields, that would be even better. Thanks for your time.